# How to prevent PDF files from automatically downloading

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i want to display pdf files in my website but unfortunately it will automatically download by idm.
here's my code:
$

```
    <div class="viewerthesispdf">
    <div id="viewer" class="pdf-viewer" data-url="<?php the_field('upload_pdfACField'); ?>"></div>
```

Comment: That is either a server configuration issue or some library you are using to read that `data-url`

Comment: It would appear you may need to provide more information about the environment

Answer (score 1):

data-url is used to embed a file in a web page. That makes sense for images. It doesn't make sense for a PDF (or Excel or Word or most other file types) because normally these types of files are in place of a page, not a section of a web page. There are generally two solutions, depending on whether the files need to be restricted:

1. Use an href tag to reference the file. `<a href="https://www.example.com/file1.pdf" target="_blank">Download File1</a>` I usually include `target="_blank"` in order to force a new page so that if there is a problem with the download you don't "lose" the original page, but it isn't strictly necessary. This will simply give a link to the file - and you can use a button, Font Awesome, images, etc. to make it fancier - but in the end "a link to a file".
2. Create a form which returns **only** the PDF as a result. Again I usually include `target="_blank"`. The advantage of a form is that (a) the file doesn't have to actually exist on disk - it can be created by a script on-the-fly (technically this can be done with a link too - but typically a link would be a file rather than a script) and (b) you can include any necessary parameters for security, user-specific customization, etc. as part of the form. The form can use a GET or a POST depending on your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Use **href** to show your pdf file list like this `<a href="<?php the_field('upload_pdfACField'); ?>"> Filename </a>`, it will not start downloading automatically, only when user click on it, it will start download.